# Statement Has Already Been Closed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, weblogic

I have an issue where on a dev server (running Weblogic 10.3.6), running a process will result in this:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Statement has already been closed
```

All database operations (insert/update mostly) still occur and seem correct.However, running in a local instance on my own workstation does NOT trigger that exception.

This code app runs Spring and Hibernate, and the triggering code runs inside a programmatic transaction.

Can anyone provide troubleshooting ideas?

Comment: Please include a stacktrace, and the code that triggers this exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you post full stacktrace it will be very easy to answer. But I will give you advice for solution. For my practice `java.sql.SQLException: Statement has already been closed` means that your `Statement` time out. When statements timeout you will get preceding exception. The following will help you how to configure `Statement` timeout and etc.
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

Comment: Usually the error means you execute an operation after the statement was closed using `close()`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you must take care to close and to initialize the Statment, ResultSet and Connection, those issues can lead to bad behavior, for example, you could have somethig like this:

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;

try {
   conn = getConnection ();
   for (TableBean tableBean : listTableBean) {
      ps = conn.prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO table (id, desc) values (?, ?)");
      ps.setInt (1, tableBean.getId());
      ps.setString (2, tableBean.getDesc());
      ps.executeUpdate();
   }
} catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
   try {
      if (ps != null) {
         ps.close();
      }
   } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   } finally {
      try {
         if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
         }
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

How you can see, `ps` is never closed until the loop ends, for this reason the Database could throw a timeout error, because in this case 
the database is the one responsible for closing sessions. It's best to close sessions when it's necessary.

```
 Connection conn = null;
 PreparedStatement ps = null;
 for (TableBean tableBean : listTableBean) {
    try {
       conn = getConnection ();
       ps = conn.prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO table (id, desc) values (?, ?)");
       ps.setInt (1, tableBean.getId());
       ps.setString (2, tableBean.getDesc());
       ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
       try {
          if (ps != null) {
             ps.close();
          }
       } catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
          try {
             if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
             }
          } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

I hope this information helps you

Good Luck.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using a Spring/Hibernate combo, and not directly using JDBC. Therefore, all of the Connection and Statement work is out of my hands.